# Error 4048 when trying to install Yeoman SharePoint generator

Tags: spfx, spfx-tooling

After running the following command:

```
npm install -g @microsoft/generator-sharepoint
```

For some reason, it wants to rename `"generator-sharepoint-77d8330f" to "generator-sharepoint"` and it fails when doing that.

**Log file (npm-debug):**

```
120379 warn optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\@microsoft\generator-sharepoint\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
120380 warn notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
120381 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Valid OS:    darwin
120381 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Valid Arch:  any
120381 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Actual OS:   win32
120381 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Actual Arch: x64
120382 verbose stack Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\.staging\@microsoft\generator-sharepoint-77d8330f' -> 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\@microsoft\generator-sharepoint'
120382 verbose stack     at whenOldMovedAway (C:\Users\developer\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v6.11.0\node_modules\npm\lib\install\action\finalize.js:43:5)
120382 verbose stack     at C:\Users\developer\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v6.11.0\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\rename.js:13:14
120382 verbose stack     at CB (C:\Users\developer\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v6.11.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:93:17)
120382 verbose stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)
120382 verbose stack
120382 verbose stack Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\.staging\@microsoft\generator-sharepoint-77d8330f' -> 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\@microsoft\generator-sharepoint'
120382 verbose stack     at Error (native)
120383 verbose cwd C:\Windows\system32
120384 error Windows_NT 10.0.15063
120385 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "@microsoft/generator-sharepoint"
120386 error node v6.11.0
120387 error npm  v3.10.10
120388 error path C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\.staging\@microsoft\generator-sharepoint-77d8330f
120389 error code EPERM
120390 error errno -4048
120391 error syscall rename
120392 error Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\.staging\@microsoft\generator-sharepoint-77d8330f' -> 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\@microsoft\generator-sharepoint'
120392 error     at whenOldMovedAway (C:\Users\developer\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v6.11.0\node_modules\npm\lib\install\action\finalize.js:43:5)
120392 error     at C:\Users\developer\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v6.11.0\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\rename.js:13:14
120392 error     at CB (C:\Users\developer\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v6.11.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:93:17)
120392 error     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)
120392 error
120392 error Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\.staging\@microsoft\generator-sharepoint-77d8330f' -> 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\@microsoft\generator-sharepoint'
120392 error     at Error (native)
120392 error  Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\.staging\@microsoft\generator-sharepoint-77d8330f' -> 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\@microsoft\generator-sharepoint'
120392 error     at whenOldMovedAway (C:\Users\developer\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v6.11.0\node_modules\npm\lib\install\action\finalize.js:43:5)
120392 error     at C:\Users\developer\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v6.11.0\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\rename.js:13:14
120392 error     at CB (C:\Users\developer\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v6.11.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:93:17)
120392 error     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)
120392 error
120392 error Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\.staging\@microsoft\generator-sharepoint-77d8330f' -> 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\@microsoft\generator-sharepoint'
120392 error     at Error (native)
120393 error Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
120394 verbose exit [ -4048, true ]
```

Comment: You might want to try: `npm i @microsoft/generator-sharepoint`

Comment: Looks like a permission issue, can you try opening command prompt using admin account ?

Comment: Also - Can you try the global uninstall (npm -g uninstall @microsoft/generator-sharepoint) then a global install (npm -g install @microsoft/generator-sharepoint) ?

Comment: strangely enough it worked after I ran `npm -g install npm`

Comment: My installation error fixed by uninstall & install like @PatMill_MSFT said